# Multiprocessing a big amount of data in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm trying to use Multiprocessing as a way to speed up my data treatment. My data consists of 3000json files and my code goes something like:

```
def analyse_page(file, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    with open(file) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    for i in range(data):
        data[i] = treat_item(data[i], arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
    with open(output_json, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(f,data)

for file in files:
    analyse_page(file, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)

print('done!')
```

So the idea is to treat items of a json, and then output a modified json. I see that my computer uses 15% Cpu power for a simple For loop, so I decided to use Multiprocessing but I get a problem that I can't understand. I've already tried Process and Pool, both in chunks and entirely, however, everytime it can always do a third of the files and then the script stops without error!

So I launch the code again using `if os.path.exists(): continue` So that the treated files are ignored. And even like this, it does another third of the files and stops. So when i launch it one more time it does the other third and then it prints `done!`

The `analyse_page` function takes approximately 3s per page, therefore what is the correct way to launch the same function in multiprocessing for a long time?

Update, what I've already done:

Processing

```
processes = []
for file in files:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=analyse_page, args=(file, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4,))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()
for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

Process with batch

```
def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

processes = []
numberOfThreads = 6 #Max is 8
For file in files:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=analyse_page, args=(file, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4,))
    processes.append(p)

for i in chunks(processes,numberOfThreads):
    for j in i:
        j.start()
    for j in i:
        j.join()
```

Pool

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(6)
For file in files:
    pool.map(analyse_page, (file, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4,))
pool.close()
```

Comment: Do you mind to show us what did you try with multiprocessing?

Comment: yeah sure, let me edit the question to put the different methods i've done

Comment: With the pool call can you try without the for loop, simply call: pool.map(analyse_page, files)

Comment: i'll try this and see

Comment: I didnt put it here, but my actual method `analyse_page` uses 6 arguments, so if i want to use pool, i would have to create a list of item, each item having the 6 arguments i guess

Answer (score 0):

Fo an easy handling of multiprocessing you can use the *concurrent.futures* module.

[Python Documentation: Concurrent Futures](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/concurrent.futures.html)

Before I´m explaining every aspect, there is a great and easy video tutorial with sample code (easy to adapt):

[YouTube: Tutorial Multiprocessing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso)

For handling many tasks with multiple processors or threads i recommend the Queue module.

[Python Documentation: Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)

```
from queue import Queue

#Create Queue object
q = Queue()

#Put item to queue
q.put("my value")

#Get and process each item in queue and remove it
while not q.empty():
    myValue = q.get()
```

Comment: i'll give a check to all of these infos! :)